# Check the render method of `UserActionApp`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-bootstrap, webapi

I am new to react was trying to implement CRUD operations in React JS using web API. However, I am receiving an error which I do not understand.

The error is this:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

    ▶ 20 stack frames were collapsed.
    Module../src/index.js
    D:/crud-app/src/index.js:7
       4 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';  
       5 | import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  
       6 | import UserActionApp from './UserCRUD/UserAction'; 
    >  7 | ReactDOM.render(<UserActionApp />, document.getElementById('root'));  
       8 | serviceWorker.unregister();
       9 | 
      10 | // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
    View compiled
```

I am using useractionapp component in the file user action.js
Here is the code for index.js:

```
    import React from 'react';  
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';  
    import './index.css';  
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';  
    import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';  
    import UserActionApp from './UserCRUD/UserAction'; 
    ReactDOM.render(<UserActionApp />, 
    document.getElementById('root'));  
    serviceWorker.unregister();
    


Here is the code for User Action:

    import React, { Component } from 'react';  
      
    import { Container, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';  
    import UserList from './GetUser';  
    import AddUser from './AddUser';  
    import axios from 'axios';
        
    const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:44360/api/User/';  
      
    class UserActionApp extends Component {  
      constructor(props) {  
        super(props);  
      
        this.state = {  
          isAddUser: false,  
          error: null,  
          response: {},  
          userData: {},  
          isEdituser: false,  
          isUserDetails:true,  
        }  
      
        this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);  
      
      }  
      
      onCreate() {  
        this.setState({ isAddUser: true });  
        this.setState({ isUserDetails: false });  
      }  
      onDetails() {  
        this.setState({ isUserDetails: true });  
        this.setState({ isAddUser: false });  
      }  
      
      onFormSubmit(data) {  
        this.setState({ isAddUser: true });  
        this.setState({ isUserDetails: false });  
        if (this.state.isEdituser) {  
         axios.put(apiUrl + 'UpdateEmployeeDetails',data).then(result => {  
          alert(result.data);  
            this.setState({  
              response:result,    
              isAddUser: false,  
              isEdituser: false  
            })  
          });  
        } else {  
         
         axios.post(apiUrl + 'InsertUserDetails',data).then(result => {  
          alert(result.data);  
            this.setState({  
              response:result,    
              isAddUser: false,  
              isEdituser: false  
            })  
          });  
        }  
        
      }  
      
      editUser = userId => {  
      
        this.setState({ isUserDetails: false });  
       axios.get(apiUrl + "GetUserDetailsById/" + userId).then(result => {  
      
            this.setState({  
              isEdituser: true,  
              isAddUser: true,  
              userData: result.data           
            });  
          },  
          (error) => {  
            this.setState({ error });  
          }  
        )  
         
      }  
      
      render() {  
        
        let userForm;  
        if (this.state.isAddUser || this.state.isEditUser) {  
      
          userForm = <AddUser onFormSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} user={this.state.userData} />  
           
        }  
        return (  
          <div className="App">  
     <Container>  
            <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>CURD operation in React</h1>  
            <hr></hr>  
            {!this.state.isUserDetails && <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.onDetails()}> User Details</Button>}  
            {!this.state.isAddUser && <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.onCreate()}>Add User</Button>}  
            <br></br>  
            {!this.state.isAddUser && <UserList editUser={this.editUser} />}  
            {userForm}  
            </Container>  
          </div>  
        );  
      }  
    }  
    export default UserActionApp;
```

Could you please help out in pointing out the error. Also I am using a different name for the file and the component. Is that causing an issue?

Comment: What happens if your condition for userForm is false? It's gonna try to render `undefined` inside the component, that's why you're getting the error. Try supplying userForm only when your condition is true, otherwise return null.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly I should do?

Comment: are you talking about this?
let userForm;  
    if (this.state.isAddUser || this.state.isEditUser) {  
  
      userForm = <AddUser onFormSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} user={this.state.userData} />  
       
    }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Element type invalid: expected a string or a class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62775998/element-type-invalid-expected-a-string-or-a-class-function)

Comment: @sandeeppradhan How is this question different from the one you asked earlier?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue comes from here, try this way:

```
render() {  
    return (  
      <div className="App">  
 <Container>  
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>CURD operation in React</h1>  
        <hr></hr>  
        {!this.state.isUserDetails && <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.onDetails()}> User Details</Button>}  
        {!this.state.isAddUser && <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.onCreate()}>Add User</Button>}  
        <br></br>  
        {!this.state.isAddUser && <UserList editUser={this.editUser} />}  
        {((this.state.isAddUser || this.state.isEditUser) && (
          <AddUser onFormSubmit={this.onFormSubmit} user={this.state.userData} /> 
        )) || null}
       </Container>  
      </div>  
    );  
  }  
}
```

The reason for this is that if your condition inside render is false, `userForm` is undefined and react tries to render undefined, running into problems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi tried the above method but still getting the same error

Comment: Could it be something else?

Comment: @sandeeppradhan where are you importing the AddUser component?

Comment: I am importing adduser function in User Action only

Comment: Is that what you were asking?

Comment: There is no import of AddUser inside UserActionApp component, at least not in the code you've provided.

Comment: There I have provided the import code in the question above. I have used import add user in this

Comment: Okay, it's getting hard to debug like this. What I suggest you do is comment out line by line in render to see which line is giving you the problem, then see what is wrong. Maybe you're not exporting the component correctly.